# About Direct Sums

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be a linear space, and $A, B, C$ are subspaces of $X$ such that $X=A\oplus B$ (i.e. $A+B=X$ and $A\cap B=\{0\}$). Under what condition do we have $C=A\cap C+ B\cap C?$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @blargoner I showed (with simple proof) that if in addition, $A\subset C$ or $B\subset C,$  then  $C=A\cap C + B\cap C.$  But the problem is in the general case if it is true.

Comment: Then you’re done! The problem asks you to *find a condition* that made the equality true. The condition is: $A \subset C$ or $B \subset C$.

Comment: Is a necessary and sufficient condition or just a sufficient condition? In other words, are there any other sufficients conditions on $C?$

Comment: We also have that if $C \subset A$ or $C \subset B,$ then, by the modular law,  $C=A\cap C+ B\cap C.$ What can we say in the general case, or if $C$ has a finite-dimensional complementary?

Comment: It's just a sufficient condition, I'm afraid. For example, if $A \oplus B = X$ where $A$ and $B$ are both proper subspaces of $X$, then $C = X$ is contained in neither, but satisfies $C = A \cap C + B \cap C$. While other equivalent statements can certainly be found, I can't think of anything that's non-obvious enough to be a clear answer to this question. Do you have any idea of what kind of characterisation you're looking for?

Comment: @TheoBendit What can we say in the case where there exists a finite-dimensional subspace $F$ such that $X=C\oplus F?$

Comment: @Luffy I can't think of anything striking when $X$ is finite-dimensional, let alone when $C$ has finite codimension. Is there a purpose that you had in mind for this characterisation?